# Update master table with updated values and new values from daily information

Tags: vba, excel

Im currently attempting to create a script that which when run it looks at all the unique values in cells A5 down to last row used in the **daily sheet**. With each of these values they must look in the **master sheet** from A3 down to last row used.

If the unique value already exists in the **master sheet**, it must copy the new values from B&Row to H&Row in the **daily sheet** over the existing values in the **master sheet** from B&Row to H&Row. If the unique value does not exists it must put it at the next available row along with it corresponding data from B&Row to H&Row.

below is the code I'm currently trying to execute but it will not work the section in question is **"'For all Downtimes in Daily Shift Report find if they are new or update existing in mastersheet**";

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()
Dim C As Range
Dim lastC As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim eRow As Long
Dim w1 As Workbook
Dim w2 As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Clear workers on shift
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\" & Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm"
Sheets("Cover").Activate
lastC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 16
With Range("B13:F50")
  .ClearContents
End With

'Open Mastersheet and define empty row in Downtimes
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\ShiftReportMaster.xlsx")
Set w1 = Workbooks(Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm")
Set w2 = Workbooks("ShiftReportMaster.xlsx")
lastRow = Workbooks(w1).Worksheets("Downtime").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
eRow = Workbooks(w2).Worksheets("Downtimes").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'For all Downtimes in Daily Shift Report find if they are new or update existing in mastersheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For n = 5 To lastRow
    v = Application.Match(Workbooks(w1).Worksheets("Downtime").Cells(n, 1), Workbooks(w2).Worksheets("Downtimes").Columns("A"), 0)
    eRow = eRow + 1
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            Workbooks(w2).Worksheets("Downtimes").Range("cells(v,2):cells(v,15)").Value = Workbooks(w1).Worksheets("Downtime").Range("cells(v,2):cells(v,15)").Value
        Else
            Workbooks(w2).Worksheets("Downtimes").Range("cells(eRow,1):cells(eRow,15)").Value = Workbooks(w1).Worksheets("Downtime").Range("cells(v,1):cells(v,15)").Value
        End If
Next n*

'Save and close mastersheet with changes and clear all information to make new template for next shift
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workbooks("ShiftReportMaster.xlsx").Close savechanges:=True

Sheets("downtime").Range("A1:O100").ClearContents 'clear downtimes
Sheets("downtime").Range("Q5:T100").ClearContents 'clear delays
Sheets("workorder").Range("A8:BZ100").ClearContents 'clear workorder information
Sheets("Time confirmations").Range("A2:L100").ClearContents 'clear time confirmation information
Sheets("cover").Range("E5:E7").ClearContents 'clear Crew, Supervisor and Coordinator


Sheets("Cover").Activate
If Range("E4").Value = "DS" Then
    Range("E4").Value = "NS"
Else
    Range("E4").Value = "DS"
    Range("F3").Value = Range("F3").Value + 1
End If


'If next shifts report doesnt exist in folder already, create it other wise skip this step
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If Dir("C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\" & Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm") = "" Then

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True, Filename:="C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\" & Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm", RouteWorkbook:=False
End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `Im currently attempting to create a script` It would help the community a lot if you're going to provide what you have attempted.

Comment: There are a few steps in that process - it would help your question if you could outline which specific part of the task is giving you problems.

Comment: Essentially im trying to figure the best way to go about it as I still consider myself quite an amateur.

Comment: I've been looking at using the range.find method for each value in dailysheet.A5:AlastRow and finding it in mastersheet.A5:AlastRow.
For each match that is found, I would like it to copy dailysheet.BRowMatch:HRowmatch over mastersheetBRowMatch:HRowmatch.
For the no match values I would like the values dailysheet.ARow:HRow copied to the next empty row in Mastersheet

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Please see code below for solution;

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()
Dim C As Range
Dim lastC As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim eRow As Long
Dim w1 As Workbook
Dim w2 As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim Fname As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Fname = Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm"
'Clear workers on shift
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\" & Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm"
Sheets("Cover").Activate
lastC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 16
With Range("B13:F50")
  .ClearContents
End With
'Open Mastersheet and define empty row in Downtimes
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\ShiftReportMaster.xlsx")
Set w1 = Workbooks(Fname)
Set w2 = Workbooks("ShiftReportMaster.xlsx")
lastRow = w1.Worksheets("Downtime").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
eRow = w2.Worksheets("Downtimes").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'For all Downtimes in Daily Shift Report find if they are new or update existing in mastersheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For n = 5 To lastRow
    v = Application.Match(w1.Worksheets("Downtime").Cells(n, 1), w2.Worksheets("Downtimes").Columns("A"), 0)
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            w1.Activate
            w1.Worksheets("Downtime").Activate '.Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, 15)).Select
            w1.Worksheets("Downtime").Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 15)).Copy
            w2.Activate
            w2.Worksheets("Downtimes").Range(Cells(v, 2), Cells(v, 15)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Else
            eRow = eRow + 1
            w1.Activate
            w1.Worksheets("Downtime").Activate '.Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, 15)).Select
            w1.Worksheets("Downtime").Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, 15)).Copy
            w2.Activate
            w2.Worksheets("Downtimes").Range(Cells(eRow, 1), Cells(eRow, 15)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If

Next n
'Save and close mastersheet with changes and clear all information to make new template for next shift
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workbooks("ShiftReportMaster.xlsx").Close savechanges:=True
Sheets("downtime").Range("A1:O100").ClearContents 'clear downtimes
Sheets("downtime").Range("Q5:T100").ClearContents 'clear delays
Sheets("workorder").Range("A8:BZ100").ClearContents 'clear workorder information
Sheets("Time confirmations").Range("A2:L100").ClearContents 'clear time confirmation information
Sheets("cover").Range("E5:E7").ClearContents 'clear Crew, Supervisor and Coordinator

Sheets("Cover").Activate
If Range("E4").Value = "DS" Then
    Range("E4").Value = "NS"
Else
    Range("E4").Value = "DS"
    Range("F3").Value = Range("F3").Value + 1
End If

'If next shifts report doesnt exist in folder already, create it other wise skip this step
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If Dir("C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\" & Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm") = "" Then

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True, Filename:="C:\Users\sreilly\Documents\test\" & Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Text & ".xlsm", RouteWorkbook:=False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```